# Finding an EPSG code for a LiDAR file given only its metadata

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, well-known-text

I am working with v1.4 .las files from El Paso County, CO, that individually appear without any reference to their projections (none that R sees, anyway).  From the metadata I can see the following information:

```
<spref>
 <horizsys>
  <planar>
   <gridsys>
    <gridsysn>State Plane Coordinate System 1983</gridsysn>
     <spcs>
      <spcszone>0502</spcszone>
      <lambertc>
       <stdparll>38.450000</stdparll>
       <stdparll>39.750000</stdparll>
       <longcm>-105.500000</longcm>
       <latprjo>37.833333</latprjo>
       <feast>3000000.000316</feast>
       <fnorth>999999.999996</fnorth>
      </lambertc>
    </spcs>
   </gridsys>
  <planci>
   <plance>coordinate pair</plance>
    <coordrep>
     <absres>0.001</absres>
     <ordres>0.001</ordres>
    </coordrep>
    <plandu>survey feet</plandu>
  </planci>
</planar>
 <geodetic>
  <horizdn>D_NAD_1983_2011</horizdn>
   <ellips>Geodetic Reference System 80</ellips>
   <semiaxis>6378137.000000</semiaxis>
   <denflat>298.257222</denflat>
  </geodetic>
 </horizsys>
<vertdef>
 <altsys>
  <altdatum>North American Vertical Datum of 1988 Geoid12B</altdatum>
  <altres>0.001</altres>
  <altunits>feet</altunits>
   <altenc>
   Explicit elevation coordinate included with horizontal coordinates
   <altenc>
  </altsys>
 </vertdef>
</spref>
```

Nowhere in the metadata is any reference made to an epsg or to esri code

This appears to correspond to blocks of information for at least 5 of 12 "Colorado Central 502" projections I have identified on epsg.io. (2232, 3502, 2877, 6428, and 102654)

lasinfo returns the OGC COORDINATE SYSTEM WKT string, but no EPSG. (I'm not skilled with lastools, but I tried...)

My questions are:

- How does one definitively identify the EPSG that goes with the projection content given in LiDAR metadata when the metadata omits the EPSG code?
- If the content in the above metadata and that of any EPSG code all match, does it make any difference which EPSG code I chose?  If so, what additional parameters matter?
- Is there a site that receives the detail above as input and returns the EPSG code, not the other way around? "http://prj2epsg.org/search" appears to be dead.

Comment: The EPSG registry (https://epsg.org/) provides a swagger API to query the database, you need to register to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a semi-solution:

```
# find epsg
# https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/earth-analytics/spatial-data-r/understand-epsg-wkt-and-other-crs-definition-file-types/

library(rgdal)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
epsg <- make_EPSG()
head(epsg)
epsg %>%
  filter(code == 2232)

epsg.step1 <- epsg %>%
   filter(str_detect(prj4, 'lat_0=37.8333333333333')) # 11 returns
epsg.step2 <- epsg.step1 %>%
  filter(str_detect(prj4, 'proj=lcc')) # 11 returns
epsg.step3 <- epsg.step2 %>%
  filter(str_detect(prj4, 'x_0=914401.828803658')) # 5 returns
epsg.step4 <- epsg.step3 %>%
  filter(str_detect(prj4, 'datum=NAD83')) # 2 returns, one of which is 2232
epsg.step5 <- epsg.step4 %>%
  filter(str_detect(prj4, 'ellps=GRS80')) # no returns, even though 2232 uses the GRS80 ellipse


# <gridsysn>State Plane Coordinate System 1983</gridsysn>
# <spcszone>0502</spcszone>
# <lambertc>
# <stdparll>38.450000</stdparll>
# <stdparll>39.750000</stdparll>
# <longcm>-105.500000</longcm>
# <latprjo>37.833333</latprjo>
# <feast>3000000.000316</feast>
# <fnorth>999999.999996</fnorth>
# <plance>coordinate pair</plance>
# <absres>0.001</absres>
# <ordres>0.001</ordres>
# <plandu>survey feet</plandu>
# <ellips>Geodetic Reference System 80</ellips>
# <semiaxis>6378137.000000</semiaxis>
# <denflat>298.257222</denflat>
# <altdatum>North American Vertical Datum of 1988 Geoid12B</altdatum>
# <altres>0.001</altres>
# <altunits>feet</altunits>
```

Answer (score 1):

EPSG = 2232. Based on your LiDAR metadata your LiDAR references Colorado State Plane 0502 (Central) NAD 83 in US survey feet.  [See here for a map of this coordinate reference system](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1_Z2IJckHKYfLTm7NMtJs441OWow&ll=39.37564647194173%2C-109.20931279236183&z=7), and [here for details on the EPSG code](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2232/).

Comment: @CBG - Yes, well-noted.  Are you aware of any direct method for finding any EPSG code given only the LiDAR metadata, besides manually or semi-automatically grinding through each element of detail?

Comment: No, sorry  I don't.  Not beyond writing the Python code to parse XML files.

Comment: No, the metadata says it's NAD 1983 (2011) so 6428.